# How can I change my background stylesheet fluently on PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from gui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


class Nem_Gui(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Nem_Gui,self).__init__()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.count=0
        self.styleSheet="QFrame#circular_progress{\n border-radius:150;\n background-color: qconicalgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, angle:90, stop:{STOP_1} rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:{STOP_2} rgba(85, 85, 255, 255));\n}"          

        #SET THE TİMER
        self.timerbar=QTimer(self)
        self.timerbar.start(35)
        self.timerbar.timeout.connect(self.get)

    def get(self):
        if self.count>=100:
            self.timerbar.stop()
        else:
            self.count+=1
            self.progressbar(self.count)


    def progressbar(self,value):
        value=(100-value)/100.0
        self.styleSheet=self.styleSheet.replace("{STOP_1}",str(value-0.001)).replace("{STOP_2}",str(value))
        self.ui.circular_progress.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet)
        

 
        

def run():
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=Nem_Gui()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
run()
```

This is my code, I have created an circular progress bar on qt designer; two circle in a row, bottom is bigger than upper in this way when bottom one start to rotate it looks like a circular progress bar.

[Here how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGBLu.png)

However the problem is, I'm changing my stylesheet on my code but my app doesn't show it, it only appears after loop ends like in the picture.I imitate this guy from youtube [wanderson circbar tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUnrLHbYmKA&t=2216s), he is doing what I try to explain, what went wrong in my code, can you please help me?

Comment: Typo: you're constantly overwriting the instance attribute instead of creating a local variable; change to `styleSheet = ...` and use `setStyleSheet(styleSheet)`.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, but can you explain what is the difference?

Comment: `self.styleSheet` is an instance attribute (meaning that `styleSheet` is a member of the current instance), `styleSheet` is a local variable. The former is used as a *source* for the replacement, the latter is what will be actually used for the function. If you use `self.styleSheet = self.styleSheet.replace(...)` you are *overwriting* `self.styleSheet` with the replaced string, so the second time it will be called there would be no `{STOP_1}` or `{STOP_2}` anymore. If you don't understand the mechanism behind that difference, do some research on classes/instances and the meaning of `self`.

Comment: Note that you can avoid the intermediate step by using proper string formatting: use double curly brackets in the source string except for those used for the stops (`QFrame#circular_progress{{\n ... stop:{STOP_1} ... stop:{STOP_2} rgba(85, 85, 255, 255));\n}}`), and then do `self.ui.circular_progress.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet.format(STOP_1=value-0.001, STOP_2=value))`. See [`str.format`](//docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and also [formatted string literals](//docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) for the `f'{value}'` syntax.